# Package algorithmic

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, algorithms

So my problem is whenever I try to use the `algorthmic` package, it gives me an error related to citations!
And when I comment out the `algorithmic` block, everything works fine.

I read somewhere that `algorithmic` is not compatible with `hyperref`, if that is the case how should I fix it ?

Comment: Please provide a "Minimum Working Example", some LaTeX code that we can copy-paste to try to reproduce your problem. Please also show the exact error message that you get.

Comment: We cannot help you without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexcjange.com/q/228). One thing: the packages are order-dependent, so try to load `algorithmic` _before_ `hyperref`.

Comment: Hi SalamKh [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) :) As the other users have mentioned, it is always best to provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) The process of constructing a MWE will quite often help to solve the problem, or at the very least isolate it :) Welcome to the group!

Comment: Ok, I did not know about the MWE, sorry.
I just solved my problem, I did not know that \STATE is case sensitive. Thanks anyways